# Why doesn't MSDN have any development documentation for SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I can't find any MSDN documentation specific to the SharePoint 2016 development. Even the general SharePoint development page has no mention of the 2016 version (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674607.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Most of what is applicable to 2013 is the same in 2016 with regards to server and client APIs.

Most of what is applicable to SharePoint Online especially around REST is also applicable to 2016.

For the most part Microsoft wants you to be using the client APIs (because your future is the cloud whether you like it or not) but if you really need it the server object model is there, it just isn't going to be updated in any significant way anymore.

Comment: I understand that but I've observed some error messages which sounded like some properties were deprecated from some classes in SP 2016. Even if the APIs are identical, shouldn't they at least have a landing page where they redirect the developers to the 2013 docs?